# How do you perform Cron job if your hosting does not provide a cron job control panel?

Tags: php, cron

I am using PHP for my application. I have a demo site and need to clean database regularly. I thought it can be done with a cronjob.

However my hosting does not provide a cron job cotroll panel.

What is the best way to perform cron job?

How do you perform it if your hosting does not provide a cronjob control panel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be a hint that your hosting provider does not want you to use cron jobs, but do you have shell access?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have shell access and you don't have access to crontab or any other cron job utility, you could always use a third party service to schedule a cron job that called a script on your site and ran what you needed to.

There are a few services out there that may fit the bill nicely for what you're doing.